# Echoing the contents of an xml-file with nested tags

Tags: php, xml

I'm a total beginner, so please forgive me if this should be obvious.

I have a text file that I marked up with xml-tags like this

```
<file> 
<title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
<text>
<line>Lorem ipsum <noun>dolor</noun> sit <verb>amet</verb>, <verb>consectetur</verb> adipiscing elit.</line>
<line>Sed do eiusmod <noun>tempor</noun> <verb>incididunt</verb> ut <noun>labore</noun> et dolore magna aliqua.</line>
</text>
</file>
```

What I would like to do is use the tags to highlight certain part of the text in a later step. But first, I'd like to echo the whole text excluding the xml-tags. The output that I am looking for is

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
> Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

I tried to do this with this code, but I only get the words that are not tagged in the xml. Echoing the title works well.

```
<?php
    $xmltext = simplexml_load_file("text.xml");
?>
    <h2><?php echo $xmltext->title; ?></h2>
<?php
    foreach ($xmltext->text->line as $output) {
        echo $output;
}
?>
```

I tried using `strip_tags`, but this just made it not output anything. I'm starting to doubt if this even possible.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm a total beginner, so please forgive me if this should be obvious.

You didn't share which problem you had finding the manual (or which manual), so you have to forgive yourself in the end for not asking for it.

So now for the less obvious things. You have not written if SimpleXML is your preferred API choice to access XML, so I will think so as you have it in your question and it might explain why you run into obstacles that early.

SimpleXML is handy when you want to access the XML like a data-structure, e.g. elements are like objects with properties.

So in the beginning this works very well, let's review an example with a title element:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

$path = "text.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path);

header('content-type: text/html');

?>
<h2><?= htmlspecialchars((string)$xml->title, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5) ?></h2>
```

But then you need it a little bit different. You're interested at all the content within an element, specifically the *text-content* and first of all across all the `<text>` elements' descendants.

Lets review the `<text>` element example:

```xml
<text>
<line>Lorem ipsum <noun>dolor</noun> sit <verb>amet</verb>, <verb>consectetur</verb> adipiscing elit.</line>
<line>Sed do eiusmod <noun>tempor</noun> <verb>incididunt</verb> ut <noun>labore</noun> et dolore magna aliqua.</line>
</text>
```

Now here the "simple" in a SimpleXMLElement somehow comes to an end. You may have noticed it already and then tried by looping over the descendants etc..

If you take a look over at the sister-library named DomDocument - which is much more complicated at what it all has - but it has some pieces that would be very fitting in your scenario. Namely the [`DOMNode::textContent` property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent):

> ***textContent*** The text content of this node and its descendants.

Hey cool, just what we need, but it's DOMDocument, not SimpleXML?!

Fear not, they work together well, perhaps best shown by example:

```php
<?= htmlspecialchars(dom_import_simplexml($xml->text)->textContent, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5) ?>
```

This shows the whole text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

(you can add a line-break after each line by iterating over the line elements and after echoing the *textContent* you add the `<br>`, so looking into looping early was not such a bad idea in case you might think it was)

So and if I got your question right, this is what you're first of all looking for.

---

The example as a whole:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

$xml = simplexml_load_string(<<<XML
<file> 
<title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
<text>
<line>Lorem ipsum <noun>dolor</noun> sit <verb>amet</verb>, <verb>consectetur</verb> adipiscing elit.</line>
<line>Sed do eiusmod <noun>tempor</noun> <verb>incididunt</verb> ut <noun>labore</noun> et dolore magna aliqua.</line>
</text>
</file>
XML);

$view = new SimpleXMLElement('<v content-type="text/html"/>');
$view->title = htmlspecialchars((string)$xml->title, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
$view->text = htmlspecialchars(dom_import_simplexml($xml->text)->textContent, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);

foreach($view->attributes() as $name => $value) {
    header("$name: $value");
}
?>
<h2><?= $view->title) ?></h2>

<?= $view->text ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags` should work just fine for you.

```php
<?php

$xml = <<<TAG
<file> 
<title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
<text>
<line>Lorem ipsum <noun>dolor</noun> sit <verb>amet</verb>, <verb>consectetur</verb> adipiscing elit.</line>
<line>Sed do eiusmod <noun>tempor</noun> <verb>incididunt</verb> ut <noun>labore</noun> et dolore magna aliqua.</line>
</text>
</file>
TAG;

$xmltext = simplexml_load_string($xml);

foreach ($xmltext->text->line as $output) {
   echo strip_tags($output);
}
```

Output is:

```
Lorem ipsum  sit ,  adipiscing elit.Sed do eiusmod   ut  et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I'll leave formatting up to you.

You can try it here: https://3v4l.org/n90Hm

Answer (score 0):

Currently your `$output` is a SimpleXMLElement and when you `echo` it the internal [`toString()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method is called. Per the notes, this method does not return text content that is inside this element's children which is why certain text is excluded.

To output your variable as you want it, you'll need to first convert it to XML using the `asXML()` method, then you can use `strip_tags()`:

```
foreach ($xmltext->text->line as $output) {
    echo strip_tags($output->asXML());
}
```

https://3v4l.org/ahZ0M